# ASP.NET Membership provider password in email replace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We use the built in asp.net membership provider to handle users accounts. The default temporary passwords that the provider creates are a little too complex for our users so I've used the below code to generate one that's a little easier to key in so that they can reset their passwords. It's working perfectly to generate the new passwords and the membership provider is using it instead of the complex one.

**Here is where my issue is:** When the users request a temporary password the application emails it to them. I'm trying to replace the temporary password with the one I'm generating. You can see in the below screenshots that the password I generate appends to the bottom of the email but I can't get the <%Password%> to be replaced with my new one. What am I missing?

```
 Public Sub PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailMessageEventArgs) Handles PasswordRecovery1.SendingMail
    Dim User As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(PasswordRecovery1.UserName)
    Dim msg As String = e.Message.Body 

    Dim oldpswd As String = User.ResetPassword()
    Dim newpass As String = GetPassword()

    msg.Replace("<%Password%>", newpass)

    msg += "<p>Your new password is: " & newpass & "</p>"
    User.ChangePassword(oldpswd, newpass)

    e.Message.Body = msg
End Sub
```

[Email Template I'd like to update with newpass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z64WW.png)

[Email that goes to user still has old password and new one at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPGC0.png)

Comment: Added image of email template that I'm trying to update with new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the "<%Password%>" with "<-TemporaryPasswordArea>" in my template, then changed the msg assignment to the following and it's replacing it correctly in the email.

```
msg = msg.Replace("<-TemporaryPasswordArea>", newpass)
```